# How to fetch a boolean value from the result in angular http client (angular 5)?

Tags: angular, rest, httpresponse

I have Angular 5 app with the following service call:

```
let isExist: boolean;
this.http.get<Boolean>(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/TripExist`, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }),
      params: {id: id, name: name},
      observe: 'response'
    }).subscribe(    
        data => { isExist = data.body;
          console.log(data);
        },
        err => console. error(err)        
      );
if (isExist == true) {
  Console....
}
```

The rest api is as follow:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain") 
@Path("TripExist")
public boolean isTripExist(@QueryParam("id") String id,
        @QueryParam("name") String name) {      
    return tripDao.isTripExist(name, id); 
}
```

I'm getting in the console an HttpResponse with the boolean value in the body but I don't know how to fetch the value and assign it to a boolean value.[image]

Comment: What'e the problem? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: isExist = data I would like to get a boolean value there

Comment: As explained in the documentation (https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response), and as shown in the logs you posted, data is of type HttpResponse. You get its body using... its body property. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're passing the `observe` option there. I'm assuming that you want to read some headers or some other meta data on the response. Keeping that in mind, since you've done `{ observe: 'response' }`, you'll get the complete Response object with a lot of fields in it. But all you're concerned about is the `body` field.

So you can read it like this:

```
let isExist: boolean;

this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/TripExist`, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }),
  params: {
    id: id,
    name: name
  },
  observe: 'response'
}).subscribe(
  data => {
    isExist = data.body; // HERE data.body will have the boolean that you're looking for.
    console.log(data);
    console.log(isExist);
    if (isExist === true) { console.... }
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
```

### UPDATE:

It won't work if the `if` condition is outside the `subscribe` block. The code inside the subscribe block runs asynchronously, i.e. after the API call is done with and the response is received. But the `if` condition would run synchronously, i.e. before the `subscribe` block. So when the control reaches your `if` condition, the `isExist` variable would still be `undefined` as it hasn't been initialized and only gets initialized inside the `subscribe` block which runs **AFTER** the `if` condition is executed.

I've updated my answer with the `if` condition moved inside the `subscribe` block.

Comment: I’m not require the full response so I guess I can remove the observe option. And I’ve tried to access the value using the data.body but I couldn’t use it inside an IF expression. If (data.body == true) or if (data.body == ‘true’) both didn’t work

Comment: When printing data.body to the console I got true but it didn’t work in an IF statement from some reason.

Comment: Ive update the question with the IF statement. It coming exactly after the service call.

Comment: Sorry, I’m using the mobile now so can’t do the correct indent.

Comment: The if statement is after the subscribe block.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please have a look. It won't work with the `if` condition outside the `subscribe` block. The reason is mentioned in the updated answer.

Comment: I’ll check what’s happened when putting inside the block and update. But really I need to use it after the block somehow. I need to wait till the asynchronous call is finished.

Comment: I think we're pivoting away from the original question here. It would be great if you could close this question and ask a separate question with all the details in there. Please do add all the relevant details or else it would end up in a lot of noise just like this one.