# Angular: Still not getting the value after subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

In my ts file I have this function:

```
searchForUser() {
        this.userService.getUserByLastName(this.searchString)
            .subscribe(
                (data: User) => this.searchedUser = data
            );
        console.log('Firstname: ' + this.searchedUser.firstName);
        this.dataService.changeUser(this.searchedUser);
    }
```

In my html file I get the correct values from searchedUser. In my console.log and dataService not. Why?
When I do a second search I am getting the values from the search before.

Comment: Looks like an exact case as that of [How to fetch a boolean value from the result in angular http client (angular 5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466539/how-to-fetch-a-boolean-value-from-the-result-in-angular-http-client-angular-5) You're setting your `searchedUser` inside the `subscribe` call which will be executed asynchronously and that too, after the `console.log` and `dataService.changeUser` calls.

Comment: Unless you are unsubscribing later, you need not to subscribe again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a timing issue, move all the actions requiring the response into the subscription call back in order to access the value you need.

```
public searchForUser(): void
{
    this.userService.getUserByLastName(this.searchString).subscribe((data: User) => 
    {
        this.searchedUser = data;
        console.log('Firstname: ' + this.searchedUser.firstName);
        this.dataService.changeUser(this.searchedUser);
    });         
}
```

This errors are occurring because you are trying to access `this.searchedUser` before it has been defined in the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

move

```
console.log('Firstname: ' + this.searchedUser.firstName);
this.dataService.changeUser(this.searchedUser);
```

inside `subscribe`:

```
searchForUser() {
  this.userService.getUserByLastName(this.searchString)
    .subscribe((data: User) => {
      this.searchedUser = data;
      console.log('Firstname: ' + this.searchedUser.firstName);
      this.dataService.changeUser(this.searchedUser);
     });
 }
```

You can also check my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55726693/6713046 for explanation.